# Angular 14 mostrar y esconder componentes hijos

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Quiero esconder y mostrar los formularios de Registro/Inicio de sesión que tengo dentro de un offcanvas de Bootstrap cuando clique en un botón.

El punto es que cuando yo clique en el botón de *Log in* de mi navbar para abrir el offcanvas, quiero mostrar por defecto el componente de **Log in**. Cuando clique en el botón de *Register* que hay al final del formulario quiero esconder el componente de inicio de sesión y mostrar el componente de registro, y hacer lo propio con el botón *Log in* del formulario de registro.

**navbar.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="d-flex">

           <a href="" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight">Log in</a>
           <app-login></app-login>
           <app-register></app-register>

       </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

**login.component.html**

```
<!-- Offcanvas -->
<div class="offcanvas">
   <div class="offcanvas-body">
       <!-- Form -->
       <div>
           <form>
               <!-- Form inputs and labels-->
               <div>
                   <p> Don't have an account? <a href="">Register</a></p>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
       <!-- Form end -->
   </div>
   <!-- Offcanvas end -->
```

**register.component.html**

```
<!-- Offcanvas -->
<div class="offcanvas">
   <div class="offcanvas-body">
       <!-- Form -->
       <div>
           <form>
               <!-- Form inputs and labels -->
               <div>
                   <p> Already have an account? <a href="">Log in</a></p>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
       <!-- Form end -->
   </div>
   <!-- Offcanvas end -->
```

Hay alguna manera de esconder y mostrar estos componentes?

Answer (score 0):

disculpa tienes que trabajar con codigo Typescript ahi, crear metodos y variables. Trabajalo con botones:

## Navbar.html

```
 <nav class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="d-flex">

           <button class="nav-link" click="login()" >Log in</button>
           <app-login *ngIf="isLogin"></app-login>
           <app-register *ngIf="!isLogin"></app-register>

       </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

## Navbar.ts

```
export class Navbar {
isLogin = true;

  login(){
    this.isLogin=true;
  }
  register(){
    this.isLogin = false;
  }
}
```

Te recomiendo que veas la documentación de [Angular](https://angular.io/docs) para que conectes tus componentes Navbar con Login y Register

Comment: Saludos, ¿estás seguro que *tienes que trabajar con código TypeScript*? ¿No podría usar JavaScript solamente?